# How to add tooltip to user defined textbox on a winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `uvSelfLoadingTextBox` with multiple instances on a form.
I would like to load the tooltip with the `_value` property at run time.

I've tried

```
public ucSelfLoadingTextBox()
{
    Windows.Forms.ToolTip myToolTip;
    myToolTip.AutomaticDelay = 5000;
    myToolTip.AutoPopDelay = 50000;
    myToolTip.InitialDelay = 100;
    myToolTip.ReshowDelay = 500;

    myToolTip.SetToolTip(this, _value);
```

inside the control but that does not work.

I have tried using the tooltip that is dragged onto the form

```
    ucSelfLoadingLogicTextBox uc = new ucSelfLoadingLogicTextBox();
    toolTipA.SetToolTip(uc,uc._value );
```

and that does not work.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Are you getting some kind of exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to instantiate `myToolTip`. You need to set it to `new Tooltip()`.

Also, I don't think it's a good practice to assign the tooltip in the textbox's constructor. You could do this in [`OnCreateControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.oncreatecontrol.aspx) (that you need to override).

Your code could therefore become:

```
protected override void OnCreateControl()
{
    base.OnCreateControl();

    var myToolTip = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip
    {
        AutomaticDelay = 5000,
        AutoPopDelay = 50000,
        InitialDelay = 100,
        ReshowDelay = 500
    };

    myToolTip.SetToolTip(this, this.Text);
}
```

Comment: oops this works ok for this.Text at design time but it only shows the old value of the control e.g. text = designtime and the text value is changed by code to text = newvalue the tooltip still shows "designtime".

Comment: Is there a way to make the control refresh do i need a onChange event of some sort?

Comment: protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) Thanks wOlf got it working perfectly now thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0):

Many visible controls on windows form have ToolTip property. Just set the Tooltip with your newly created one. You can also add tooltip to your form. Have you tried this?

```
myToolTip.ShowAlways = true;
```

And try to set this tip to a button control. This may be a good test for your tooltip.